# How can I group DIVs in my document so I can apply CSS to them?

Tags: html, css

My HTML has DIVs that are used to apply background areas to different places on my page:

```
<div id="l1" class="fixed sp bg"></div>
<div id="l2" class="fixed sp fg lb"></div>
<div id="t1" class="fixed fg tb"></div>
<div id="r1" class="fixed sp fg rb"></div>
<div id="b1" class="fixed fg bb"></div>
<div id="c1" class="fixed sp bg"></div>
<div id="l4" class="fixed sp fg lb"></div>
<div id="t2" class="fixed fg tb"></div>
<div id="r3" class="fixed sp fg rb"></div>
<div id="r4" class="fixed sp bg"></div>
<div id="b2" class="fixed fg bb"></div>
<div id="bottom" class="fixed bg"></div>
```

I have CSS like this for them like this:

```
 #b1 { left: 3rem; width: 22rem; bottom: 2rem; height: 1rem; }
```

Is there a way I can group these without effecting the fact they are used for position? I tried to put all these in a  but that compleltely mess up the layout.

I just want some way in CSS to say something like:

```
.abc > #b1 { .... }
.abc > #b2 { .... }
```

or even better using LESS:

```
.abc {
    position: fixed;

    #b1 { }
    #b2 { }
}
```

Comment: Are you searching for css regex? something like [id*="b"] { // code }

Comment: No I would like to find an element that could group these that would not effect positioning. However having said that I think your comment looks very good if nothing I am looking for exists. Can you tell me how I could use: [id*="b"] { // code }  with LESS ?

Comment: Consider: <div class="group1 b1">

Comment: @Zentoaku - How could I use group1 and b1 with LESS ?

Comment: one thing I am going to add here, there is no point on using `.abc > #b1` as you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: @Marilou added answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comment:

```
<div class="group1 b1">
<div class="group1 b2">
<div class="group2 c1">
<div class="group2 c2">
```

LESS:

```
.group1 {
    &.b1 {}
    &.b2 {}
}
```